# DTO vs Formbean

Tags: java, spring-mvc, standards

I'm developing spring MVC application and I used AirPortForm.java to get information in my airport.jsp. But I'm just wandering what is the standard method do I need to use AirPortDTO.java instead of AirPortForm.java kindly advice me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Form` suffix usually indicates that the object is meant to contain values coming from an HTML form (Spring calls these command objects).

The `DTO` suffix indicates that the object is a Data Transfer Object. A Data Transfer Object is an object, usually without much logic, which is used to carry information between the presentation layer and the service layer.

Use the appropriate suffix for you use-case, or use another one or not at all if your object is neither a form nor a DTO.

Comment: So should we use view to controller (form), controller to service (dto), service to repository (model)?

Answer (score 1):

DTO use to transfer data between your database and application. Model View Controller (MVC) is one of the design pattern that separate your application with different layers. DTO is in model layer.In your application, you can use AirportFrom.java class only but it is not good practice.

Comment: So do I need to crete both Form and DTO

Comment: @user1479853,Yes you do.Try to use data access layer, business layer and presentation layer separately.